# Nextflow: How to deal with out of memory error?

Tags: aws-batch, nextflow

I wanted to test Nextflow error handling with aws batch executor. I used `stress` to fill 20GB of memory, while initially allocating only 12GB and applied standard error strategy (as in manual).

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process test {

cpus 2
memory { '12.GB' * task.attempt }
errorStrategy { task.exitStatus in 137..140 ? 'retry' : 'terminate' }
maxRetries 3

"""
stress -c 2 -t 60 --vm 20 --vm-bytes 1024M 
"""
}

workflow {
  test()
}
```

Although the error message is:

```
Caused by:
  Essential container in task exited - OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory usage
```

..the exit status is `8` (rather than 137..140, so resources are not adjusted):

```
Command exit status:
  8
```

What might be the problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: Also, you don't need quotes around the memory value, just use: `memory { 12.GB * task.attempt }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you're expecting a certain exit status (128+9 = 137) but there are really no guarantees in life. The reason you get an exit status of 8 here (or any int really) has to do with how [stress](https://web.archive.org/web/20130520190152/http://weather.ou.edu/%7Eapw/projects/stress/) works:

> It is a single file called `stress.c` whose internal organization is in
> essence a loop that forks worker processes and then waits for them to
> either complete normally or exit with an error.

So while waiting for the workers to exit, a return value (which is initialized using `retval = 0`) is incremented each time a worker returns an error. The program then exits with the return value, which provides the exit status. This ensures that we get a non-zero exit status when a single worker returns an error.

Ultimately, a decision on the most appropriate [errorStrategy](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#errorstrategy) needs to be made for each process. For the command above (i.e. stress), you may simply want `errorStrategy { 'retry' }` for testing. In production, however, I find using a [dynamic retry with exponential backoff](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#dynamic-retry-with-backoff) works quite well since we would want to 'retry' usually anyway. To make this the 'default' errorStrategy, just add this to your nextflow.config:

```
process {

  errorStrategy = {
    sleep( Math.pow( 2, task.attempt ) * 150 as long )
    return 'retry'
  }
  maxRetries = 3

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the very informative comment! Yep, it seems that stress was not the good tool to test the resource scaling behavior and as you say it requires more tailored approach - all I wanted to do is to simply see resources re-deployed (more RAM) after overflowing memory (e.g., tools such as `humann3`, which require quite lot of it).